# How do I use the blockchain file bootstrap.dat?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, solo-mining, bootstrap.dat

Once I have the 9+ Gb bootstrap.dat file downloaded, how do I use it? I'd like to attempt mining without joining a pool; do I have the right file for a solo effort? I can use Windows or Linux so either one in the answer will be fine.

Comment: Your talking about mining with the Bitcoin-Qt client, in linux "~/.bitcoin/" and in Windows find the AppData hidden directory. You can start Bitcoin-Qt and let it create the directory and stop it, remove everything inside for a clean beginning and move bootstrap to this directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run bitcoin-qt or bitcoind in command line, pass that argument. This way, the client indexes transactions from a file, not from the internet.

```
bitcoin-qt -loadblock=/path/to/bootstrap.dat
```

Source: http://eu2.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/
 Version 0.7 or later will also import this file by passing the command line argument "-loadblock=/path/to/bootstrap.dat" to bitcoin-qt or bitcoind.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it in Windows.  Download Bootstrap.dat, then look for C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin and put the file there.  Bitcoin will automatically find it and load from it.  Good luck.